# JQuery Append input name

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dropdown list with multi input choices.  Users can pick whatever they like and each time they pick, their choice will show in the field.

Problem: 
1. I try to get a value name of an input by `var inputName = $('input').attr('name');` , but somehow it does work.  Please give a hand on this issue.

2. After they pick, if they change their mind and want to delete one or more what they have chosen, how can I create a X button next to a product for deleting?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6pom2qcg/)

Thanks!

JF

```
$(function() {
        $('.field-store').click(function(){
            $('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle('fast');
    })
    $('.dropdown-menu input').click(function() {
            $('.txt-title').hide();
        var inputName = $('input').attr('name');
        $('.multi-selects').append('inputName ');
    })
})
```

HTML

```
<div class="field-store">
  <span class="txt-title">Pick what you like</span>
  <span class="multi-selects"></span>
</div>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cheese">Cheese</input>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tomatoes">Tomatoes</input>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mozarella">Mozzarella</input>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mushrooms">Mushrooms</input>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="pepperoni">Pepperoni</input>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="onions">Onions</input>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.field-store {
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 lines that are causing this.

The first is `$('.multi-selects').append('inputName ');`. You are appending a string to the element rather than the value of `inputName`. For this just simply remove the single quotes like so:

```
$('.multi-selects').append(inputName + " ");
```

The second is your `inputName` definition. You are using the `input` tag as a selector, meaning it is consistently getting the first instance of this tag. I would recommend adding an input variable, (in this case `e`), to the function in your `click()` event handler like this:

```
$('.dropdown-menu input').click(function(e) {})
```

And also change your `inputName` definition to this:

```
var inputName = $(e.target).attr('name');
```

I have also edited your jsfiddle with these changes [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5yearw0b/1/). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Jesse for pointing out what were caused the issue!  I didn't realize these.  Would you please take a look at the #2: After they pick, if they change their mind and want to delete one or more what they have chosen, how can I create a X button next to a product for deleting?  This one I have no idea how.  Thanks

Comment: I personally think it would be more efficient to remove it if they just uncheck the box, but if that won't work for your situation, then you should create a `div` containing the name of the product along with either a link or a button with either `X` or `&times;` in between the tags, then make it so when you click the `X`, simply run `$(this).remove()`

Comment: Thanks, Jesse so much.  I will try your suggestion out.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('.dropdown-menu input').click(function() {
      $('.txt-title').hide();
      var inputName = $(this).attr('name');
      if($(this).prop('checked')){
         $('.multi-selects').append('<span>'+ inputName + '</span>' );
      }else{ 
        $('.multi-selects span:contains('+inputName+')').remove()
    } 
  })
```

Comment: Thanks NarasimhaBamandla!  I really like your code, it works so well.  Thanks again!